# import csv with date to mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql, date, csv, datetime

I'm trying to upload a csv file to my mysql table with php.

I heard about the `inline` command but the problem is that the csv date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` and the mysql format is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I tried almost every `Date` convert function but it doesn't worked out. always see 0000-00-00 on the Mysql Table.

How can I convert it correctly?

This is the last thing I tried:

(`$date[0]` is the date cell in the csv. - `26/05/2016`, and the second column in the mysql is the date)

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) 
    {
        $date = strtotime($data[0]); 
        $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data[0]));
        $trydate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($newDate));
        echo $newDate . "<br>". $date. "<br>" . $data[0] . "<br>". $trydate. "<br>";
        $import="INSERT INTO `testresult` (cityid, date, testnum,result) VALUES('$data[1]','$newDate','$data[3]','$data[2]')";

        mysqli_query($con,$import) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

The output was:

```
01-01-1970
(blank)
26/05/2015
1970-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` waiting an input an [expected](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) format.

You need to split your string, and create a `Y-m-d` fromat from it, or you can use the `DateTime` object.

```
$dateString = '11/05/2016';
$Date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateString, new DateTimeZone(('UTC')));
echo $Date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2016-05-11
```

With `strtotime`

```
$string = '26/05/2016';
$trydate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(substr($string, -4) . "-" . substr($string, 3, 2) . "-" . substr($string, 0, 2)));
echo $trydate;
```

Result are the same.

Comment: I whole heartedly approve of using the `DateTime` object :)

Comment: @Catharsis I am working on a project where I should use dates what is out of the range of unix timestamp. So this was my first time when I am using `DateTime`. I can't believe that I could live without it. The other advantage is the `DateTimeZone` thing. Love it :)

Comment: @lolka_bolka Thanks! It worked... I also tried with explode ("/" etc.) and It wored too. but I'm curious..is there a way to do that if I don't know the date format in the csv? I mean kind of universal converting?

Comment: There is no universal solution. You can use the `substr` thing always, when date is in `dd[any separator]mm[any separator]yyyy` so only the separator could change. What substr things do? Get the last 4 string, add a `-` thne get the `5,6` chars add `-` string and get the first 2 chars. If this was your question. strtotime waiting yyyy-mm-dd fromat, (or Y-m-d H:i:s)

Comment: got it..
any way - Thank you very very much!! :) :) :)

Comment: You can also check out `Carbon` available via Packagist which is really powerful for dealing with time/date and timzones

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to convert the `/` to `-` so that strtotime understands the format..

for example

```
while(...) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data[0])));
    echo $date;
    $import = "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SET clause, along with a variable to reference the contents of the row at that column. In your column list, you assign your date column to a variable name. You can then use it in your SET statement.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE testresult
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(cityid, @var1, testnum,result)
set dateOfBirth = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d/%m/%y')
```