# Import csv with wrong format date to MySQL with Symfony-php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, symfony

I'm trying to upload a csv file to my mysql table with symfony/php.

```
                                    ...

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== false) {

                    $count++;
                    if ($count == 1) { continue; }

                    $entity = new Oasice();
 
                    $entity->setCentre($data[0]);
                    $entity->setAffaire($data[1]);
                    $entity->setTypeAffaire($data[2]);
                    $entity->setTypeDossier($data[3]);
                    $entity->setCommune($data[4]);
                    $entity->setCodeInsee($data[5]);
                    $entity->setMoaEr($data[6]);
                    $entity->setDateAmeoAmheo($data[7]); // date
                    $entity->setChargeAffaire($data[8]);
                    // a lot more column...
```

In this file I have ten columns with dates in the format `dd/mm/YYYY` which poses a problem for the integration into the database.

I tried the solutions I could find so far (like for example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158953/import-csv-with-date-to-mysql-through-php)) but nothing conclusive.

example

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data[7])));
dump($date)
```

but my result is often `01-01-1970` or `1970-01-01`  or empty strings.

Edit:

example of date format in multiple columns of the file:

[image: date format in multiple columns of the file]
[image: date with empty strings]

How should I go about it please? what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should give us some examples how your date is looking in your file in that cases where you get a wrong result.

Comment: The dates are all in this type of format: :  

04/04/2018

04/09/2020

19/07/2017

Comment: Have you checked if $ data[7] is empty in some cases?

Comment: It is unclear to me what Doctrine version you are using. But in case you specified the entity's `dateAmeoAmheo` property to be one of the [Doctrine date column types](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#date-and-time-types), you should just give a `DateTimeInterface` instance to `setDateAmeoAmheo`, and Doctrine will manage the appropriate date conversion for you.

So, perhaps convert the csv's date value to a `DateTime` instance before passing it to your entity.

Comment: Yes, $data[7] is empty sometimes

Comment: Hmm, my setDateAmeoAmheo is already in DateTimeinterface instance, Doctrine did it itself

Comment: Can you share more details? Why does this date format "pose a problem"? What **exactly** does that mean, and what have you tried to resolve that problem?

Comment: Well,  my first problem was :

```Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Oasice::setDateAmeoAmheo() must implement interface DateTimeInterface or be null, string given, called in ...\htdocs\myProject\src\Controller\ImportController.php on line 77```

so i tried to change the dates i have in my columns to match correct date format, not a string...


so far I have tried several methods, such as str_replace etc.


My goal is to retrieve the dates (and other data) from this csv in order to put them in my database.

Comment: and the problem is that in my date columns there are often empty strings , this is mainly what drives me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

essentially [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) (which is an alias for `Date::createFromFormat`) can create dates from various formats, especially numerical variants (like in the answer you linked yourself):

```php
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $data[7]);

// then turn it into the format you want, like Y-m-d:
// $mysqlDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
// or assign it to your entity
$entity->setDateAmeoAmheo($date);
```

if you have multiple formats, you could work with fallbacks, since `date_create_from_format` will return `false` on error:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $data[7]) 
     ?: date_create_from-format('d/m/y', $data[7])
     // and so on, if needed.
;
// rest as before
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution, not necessarily the best I guess, but I will consider it.

I will try to do this process on all my columns with dates and with empty string

I'll keep you posted if it's okay

````
      ```   $date7 = explode("/", $data[7]);
                //dump($date);
                if ($date7[0] !== "")
                {
                    $ladateameo = '"'.$date7[2].'-'.$date7[1].'-'.$date7[0].'"';
                }
                else
                {
                    $ladateameo = NULL; 
                }
                //dump($ladateameo);
                $entity->setDateAmeoAmheo($ladateameo); // date    data[7] ```
````

EDIT :

```
                    $date9 = explode("/", $data[9]);
                    dump($date9);
                    if ($date9[0] !== "")
                    {
                        dump($date9[0]);
                        $dateReceptionDossier = $date9[2].'-'.$date9[1].'-'.$date9[0];
                        dump($dateReceptionDossier);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $dateReceptionDossier = NULL;   
                    }
                    $entity->setReceptionDossier($dateReceptionDossier);
```

[image: dump]

And the problem is still there...

Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Oasice::setReceptionDossier() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, string given, called in ...\src\Controller\ImportController.php on line 85

The dates are finally in the right format but still taken for string...